# Was Martin-Löf inspired by Peirce when he introduced the dependent sum and dependent product types?

Tags: math-history, type-theory

In the following article:

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-logic/

it is mentioned that Peirce's introduced the use of the symbols $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ to express logical sums and products, but also to denote the existential and universal quantifiers. Is the use of these symbols related to their use in, for example, intuitionistic type theory as dependent sum and dependent type?

Comment: Maybe... The [Algebra of Logic tradition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra-logic-tradition/) used $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ for the quantifiers exactly because they "generalize" to the infinite case respectively: *disjunction* (i.e. logical sum) and *conjunction* (i.e. logical product).

Comment: For a finite universe $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$ $\exists n (n > 0)$ is equiv to $(n=0) \lor (n=1) \lor (n=2)$. In the algebraic logis symbolism they are: $\Sigma_n (n > 0)$ and $(n=0) + (n=1) + (n=2)$.

Comment: Yeap, it kind of makes sense since Peirce used the symbols to introduce quantification in his system, while Martin-Löf used them to introduce quantification to the simply-typed lambda calculus. But it would be nice if there were some reference that may confirm or negate this theory...